# how she is charming / how charming she is

Tags: wh-questions

What difference, if any, is there between "how charming she is" and "how she is charming" in the following?

> John understands how she is charming / how charming she is.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11):

The version

> John understands how charming she is.

is about how much charm she has.

The version

> John understands how she is charming.

is about what makes her charming or why they call her charming.

Comment: Or the second version means that John understands how she's casting spells.

Answer (score 8):

The other two answers are both correct, even though they are slightly different.

Why? Because "**He noticed how she is charming**" is ambiguous.

It can either mean:

> He noticed *that* she is charming (Tᴚoɯɐuo's interpretation)

or

> He noticed *in what way* she is charming (Alex_ander's interpretation)

With no other context clues (like the text going on to describe the specific ways in which she is charming), I'd say the first is the more likely meaning a native speaker would infer.

The other version ("**John understands how charming she is**") isn't ambiguous, it always refers to *how much charm she has*.

Comment: Ah, but her charms are many.

Comment: I would consider the use of "how" instead of "that" as somewhat informal. I agree it is the more likely interpretation, because someone writing formally would probably have avoided the ambiguity of "how" altogether.

Answer (score 4):

**how she is charming**

refers to the fact of her being charming.

**how charming she is**

refers to the degree of her charm.

> He noticed how the ladder was wobbly.
>
> He noticed how wobbly the ladder was.

The first refers to the fact that the ladder is wobbly.
The second refers to the degree of the ladder's wobble.

Answer (score 1):

> John understands **how charming she is**.

What this is saying is that John is coming to the realization that the girl is really charming. That is, he now understands that she is beautiful and attractive to a high degree. The word [**why**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/how) is an adverb and it can have many different usages, but in our case here it talks specifically about the extent or degree to which the girl is charming.

> John understands **how she is charming**.

In this example, we're saying that John has no problem understanding why or in what way people find or think that the girl charming.

---

I think this still needs more clarification, so, please take a look at the following examples:

> You will never understand **how good chocolate truffle cake is** unless you try it yourself!

The only way to understand to what degree chocolate truffle cake is good is to actually taste it.

> I don't really understand **how PCs are good**. On the contrary, I think they are total crap compared to Mac computers! *(This is just an example to make a point. I'm not trying to be offensive or anything like that.)*

Here, I'm saying that I don't understand why people think that PC computers are good. In what way are they good? I think that Macs are way better.